# Drop down list not showing as required but is marked as required

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an issue with dropdown list with MVC. but there is no issue with textboxes, only with dropdown lists. I want to first say that I spent an extensive time on that and still no solution. I also want to mention that the properties are marked with [Required] attribute. In the view, I also have jquery.min, jquery.validate.min, jquery.validate.unobstrusive.min. 
I also have :

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"> 
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true">
```

**ViewModel Code:**

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required.")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> State { get; set; }
 }
```

**in the view:**

```
<div> 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateSelectedItem, (List<SelectListItem>)Model.State)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
</div>
```

Any idea, thoughts, comment?
Thanks.

Comment: The code for the view and the code in the controller!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, please check my edit

Comment: You dont apply the attribute to a property which is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ` - you apply it to the property you binding to, which is `StateSelectedItem`. And since you not generating a `null` option then it will always have a value and can never be invalid. You need to show the definition for property `StateSelectedItem` and the way you are populating the `State` in order to give an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render your razor view, the SELECT element's `name` property value will be "StateSelectedItem" and that will have the value of the selected option. So you should apply your `Required` data annotation to that property.

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required.")]
    public string StateSelectedItem {set;get;}

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> State { get; set; }
}
```

And in your view, You do not need to cast the `Model.State` property to a `List<SelectListItem>` again as it is already a `List<SelectListItem>` type. Also create the validation message for the `StateSelectedItem` property.

```
@model RegistrationViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div> 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StateSelectedItem, Model.State, "Select one")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StateSelectedItem)
  </div>
}
```

This should work, assuming you loaded some items to your State collection property of your view model.

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
   var vm = new RegistrationViewModel();
   vm.State= new List<SelectListItem> {
                   new SelectListItem { Value="MI", Text="Michigan" },
                   new SelectListItem { Value="NY", Text="NewYork" },
             };
  return View(vm).
}
```